# Updated to iOS 4.2 and now errors

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios-4.2

I updated my SDk to iOS 4.2 and now my frameworks has a red-font and I have this error:

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'**

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your frameworks are in red-font because you haven't change you base-SDK to latest one.
Go into your target/getInfo/build and change it to 4.2, then close/open xcode and it will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in nil to initFileURLWithPath: and it's expecting a string.

Can you show some code where you create the path (and the stack trace if you have it) so we can give a more useful answer?